# How do I install the Vivaldi web browser from its software repository?

Tags: software-installation, web-browser

How can I install the Vivaldi web browser from its repository so it can be updated with apt-get commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "echo deb http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb/ stable main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vivaldi.list" | sudo sh
curl http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1397BC53640DB551
sudo apt update; sudo apt install vivaldi-stable
```